# Fetching, adding, and viewing games

Tags: c#, .net, xml, wpf, mvvm

This is a simple application that will eventually manage certain files for video games. For now, I'm only posting code that handles fetching, adding, and viewing games.

I'm trying to keep things incredibly simple and pure while learning WPF and MVVM, so my goal is to avoid frameworks. Please note that I'm not too concerned with the UI at this point, so I'm only interested in XAML/UI suggestions if they serve to improve my implementation of MVVM or if I'm missing easy/common shortcuts. Also, I'll omit the service, repository, and ViewModel classes unless they are requested.

**Model**

```cs
[SettingsSerializeAs(SettingsSerializeAs.Xml)]
public class Game : IEntity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ExecutablePath { get; set; } // e.g. Minecraft.exe

    public Game() { } // Required to be serialized as a setting.

    public Game(string name, string executablePath)
    {
        Name = name;
        ExecutablePath = executablePath;
    }
}
```

**MainView and MainViewModel** - I won't share the code for these. `MainView` simply has a GamesView and a button to open the `ManageGamesView`.

[image: MainView]

**GamesView** - A simple ComboBox (appears on the MainView above). Used to select the current game.

```xml
<UserControl x:Class="ENBOrganizer.UI.Views.GamesView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" mc:Ignorable="d" 
             xmlns:ViewModels="clr-namespace:ENBOrganizer.UI.ViewModels" xmlns:UI="clr-namespace:ENBOrganizer.UI">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <UI:PathToIconConverter x:Key="PathToIconConverter" />
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <UserControl.DataContext>
        <ViewModels:GamesViewModel />
    </UserControl.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Games}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedGame}" 
                  VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" MaxHeight="25">
            <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Image Source="{Binding ExecutablePath, Converter={StaticResource PathToIconConverter}, Mode=OneWay}" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Padding="5,0,0,0" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ComboBox>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

**GamesViewModel**

```cs
public class GamesViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private readonly GameService _gameService;
    private ObservableCollection<Game> _games;

    public ObservableCollection<Game> Games
    {
        get { return _games; }
        set { _games = value; RaisePropertyChanged("Games"); }
    }

    public Game SelectedGame
    {
        get { return Settings.Default.SelectedGame; }
        set
        {
            if ((value != null) && (Settings.Default.SelectedGame != value))
            {
                Settings.Default.SelectedGame = value;
                Settings.Default.Save();

                RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedGame");
            }
        }
    }

    public GamesViewModel()
    {
        _gameService = ServiceSingletons.GameService;
        _gameService.GamesChanged += OnGamesChanged;

        Games = new ObservableCollection<Game>(_gameService.GetAll());
    }

    private void OnGamesChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Games = new ObservableCollection<Game>(_gameService.GetAll());
    }
}
```

**`ManageGamesView`** - A screen used to add and remove games

```xml
    <Window x:Class="ENBOrganizer.UI.Views.ManageGamesView"
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            xmlns:ViewModels="clr-namespace:ENBOrganizer.UI.ViewModels" xmlns:UI="clr-namespace:ENBOrganizer.UI"
            Title="Manage Games" MinWidth="250" SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight" >
        <Window.Resources>
            <UI:PathToIconConverter x:Key="PathToIconConverter" />
        </Window.Resources>
        <Window.DataContext>
            <ViewModels:ManageGamesViewModel />
        </Window.DataContext>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition />
                <RowDefinition />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <Grid Grid.Row ="0">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition />
                    <RowDefinition />
                    <RowDefinition />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <Label Content="Name:" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                <TextBox Text="{Binding Name}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" MinWidth="100" Margin="5" />

                <Label Content="Path:" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                <TextBox Text="{Binding ExePath}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" MaxWidth="300" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="5" />
                <Button Content="Browse..." Command="{Binding BrowseCommand}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,5,0" />

                <StackPanel Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right" >
                    <Button Content="Remove" Command="{Binding RemoveGameCommand}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,5,0" />
                    <Button Content="Add" Command="{Binding AddGameCommand}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" />
                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>

            <StackPanel Grid.Row="1"  Orientation="Vertical">
                <TextBlock>Games</TextBlock>
                <ListView Name="GamesListView" ItemsSource="{Binding Games}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedGame}" >
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <Image Source="{Binding ExecutablePath, Converter={StaticResource PathToIconConverter}, Mode=OneWay}" />
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Padding="5,0,0,0" />
                            </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

It ends up looking like this:

[image: ManageGamesView]

**`ManageGamesViewModel`**

```cs
public class ManageGamesViewModel : ViewModelBase, IDataErrorInfo 
{
    private readonly GameService _gameService;
    private ObservableCollection<Game> _games;
    private Game _selectedGame;
    private string _name, _exePath;

    public ICommand RemoveGameCommand { get; set; }
    public ICommand AddGameCommand { get; set; }
    public ICommand BrowseCommand { get; set; }

    public ObservableCollection<Game> Games
    {
        get { return _games; }
        set { _games = value; RaisePropertyChanged("Games"); }
    }

    public Game SelectedGame
    {
        get { return _selectedGame; }
        set
        {
            _selectedGame = value;

            if (value == null)
                return;

            Name = value.Name;
            ExePath = value.ExecutablePath;
        }
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set { _name = value; RaisePropertyChanged("Name"); }
    }

    public string ExePath
    {
        get { return _exePath; }
        set { exePath = value; RaisePropertyChanged("ExePath"); }
    }

    public ManageGamesViewModel()
    {
        _gameService = ServiceSingletons.GameService;
        _gameService.GamesChanged += OnGamesChanged;

        Games = new ObservableCollection<Game>(_gameService.GetAll());

        RemoveGameCommand = new ActionCommand(RemoveGame, CanRemove);
        AddGameCommand = new ActionCommand(AddGame, CanAdd);
        BrowseCommand = new ActionCommand(BrowseForGameFile, () => true);
    }

    private void AddGame()
    {
        Game game = new Game(Name, ExePath);
        _gameService.Add(game);
    }

    private bool CanAdd()
    {
        Game game = new Game(Name, ExePath);
        return _gameService.ValidateGame(game);
    }

    private void BrowseForGameFile()
    {
        OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog
        {
            Filter = "EXE Files (*.exe)|*.exe",
            Title = "Select the game's .exe file"
        };

        if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
        {
            Name = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(openFileDialog.FileName);
            ExePath = openFileDialog.FileName;
        }
    }

    private void RemoveGame()
    {
        _gameService.Delete(SelectedGame);
    }

    private bool CanRemove()
    {
        return SelectedGame != null;
    }

    private void OnGamesChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Games = new ObservableCollection<Game>(_gameService.GetAll());
    }
}
```

Please note that the `SelectedGame` property here is simply what is selected in the ListView. `SelectedGame` in `GamesViewModel` is an application setting.

### Key Concerns

My concerns are pretty much all related to one another. I could be worrying about nothing, but I can't fight this feeling that I'm missing a pattern or solution that would address all of these issues at once:

1. I'm using an event, `GamesChanged`, in the GameService class to alert my ViewModel to CRUD operations. This feels wrong and slightly WinForms-ish. I thought of implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` in my service class, but I'm not quite sure that would work since I would have to invent a new property to watch. I also considered not listening to the service at all and manually updating the UI, i.e. adding/removing from the `ObservableCollection` after a service call. However, issue 2 explains my dilemma there.
2. Because of issue 1, I needed the same instance of `GameService` in both `GamesViewModel` and `ManageGamesViewModel` so that they could each react to changes to the data simultaneously, e.g. adding a new game in the Manage Games screen refreshes the ComboBox on the main screen. Assuming I've taken the right approach in using an event from the service, is my use of a singleton property acceptable? In WinForms, I would have passed an instance of `GameService` in the constructor of the form, but I don't believe that's possible for my ViewModel because it is instantiated in XAML without arguments. Since I'm trying to stay very simple, I'd like to avoid an IoC container right now.
3. This also hinges on issue 1, but I'm skeptical of how I refresh the `ObservableCollection<Game>` property in the `GamesViewModel` and `ManageGamesViewModel`. I do like how simple it is, but it seems I don't even need `ObservableCollection` here. That could just as well be a plain ol' `List<Game>`.

I think that does it for now. Feel free to offer any suggestions. Although I'm trying to avoid frameworks, I'm open to using them if they simplify my design and/or easily resolve my issues.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You should only use `OneTime` bindings when binding to classes which do not implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface, otherwise those bindings will leak memory. If you need a `TwoWay` binding to your `Game`, then you should wrap it into `GameViewModel`. Same goes for collections and `INotifyCollectionChanged`. Using plain ol' `List<Game>` as `ItemsSource` will leak memory too.
2. Singletons... just don't. Simply pass the service into constructors manually or using some `DI` container.
3. You should avoid re-creating `ObservableCollection`. Call `Clear` and repopulate it instead, when you need to reload it.
4. I think the simplest way to address your concerns is to share single `ObservableCollection` of your games between the viewmodels that need it. This way you won't have to bother with synchronization. There are multiple ways to achieve this. For example, you could create a child view model to represent the list of games, and inject it everywhere its needed. Or you could re-organize your UI in a way, that there is only one place where list of games is displayed. Or you could even return `ObservableCollection` from your service class, and expose it from your viewmodels (keep in mind the point #1 about `OneTime` bindings though).
5. I think it is generally a bad idea to `Save` settings in property setter. Writing to disk can be expensive and it can lag. You should perform I/O operations either in background or when user closes the window.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. Using a child view model for the list of games sounds appealing and would reduce duplication. There are surprisingly few resources on using child view models/ I'm guessing I need to pass the child view model into the constructor of the parent, but I'm not sure where to do that. I suppose I'll have to initialize the parent ViewModel in the code-behind instead of in XAML so I can use parameters?

Comment: @SeeSharpCode , yes, you should probably move all initialization logic to `Startup` event of your `Application` class.

Answer (score 5):

Disclaimer: I don't review Xaml, I focus on the C# part only.

> ```
> [SettingsSerializeAs(SettingsSerializeAs.Xml)]
> public class Game : IEntity
> {
>     public string Name { get; set; }
>     public string ExecutablePath { get; set; } // e.g. Minecraft.exe
>
>     public Game() { } // Required to be serialized as a setting.
>
>     public Game(string name, string executablePath)
>     {
>         Name = name;
>         ExecutablePath = executablePath;
>     }
> }
> ```

The first comment `// e.g. Minecraft.exe` is only adding noise to the code. Its perfectly clear that the `ExecutablePath` property holds exactly what the name implies. Adding the comment doesn't make this more clear.

The second comment is a **good** comment, because it describes **why** the constructor is `public`. One could say that the constructor could be omitted because it is added by default, but IMO it makes the indent more clear.

---

**GamesViewModel**

> ```
> public ObservableCollection<Game> Games
> {
>     get { return _games; }
>     set { _games = value; RaisePropertyChanged("Games"); }
> }
> ```

Vertical space aka new lines doesn't cost anything, you should use them to make your code more readable. At first glance (especially with old eyes) it is hard to see that the setter consist of two instructions. Do yourself and **Sam the maintainer** something good and use some more lines here like

```
public ObservableCollection<Game> Games
{
    get { return _games; }
    set 
    {    
        _games = value; 
        RaisePropertyChanged("Games"); 
    }
}
```

If you by any chance are using C# 6.0 (implemented in VS 2015) you should use the [`nameof`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986596.aspx) operator like so

```
public ObservableCollection<Game> Games
{
    get { return _games; }
    set 
    {    
        _games = value; 
        RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(Games)); 
    }
}
```

which has the advantage, if you choose to rename the property to something else using the default refactoring tools ( Rename F2 ) this will be changed too.

In the `SelectGame` property setter the doubled brackets `if ((value != null) && (Settings.Default.SelectedGame != value))` are not needed. You can change this to

```
if (value != null && Settings.Default.SelectedGame != value)
```

I don't really like the saving of the `Setting.Default` in this setter. I have the feeling that this should belong to somewhere else, but not in the `ViewModel` which should be responsible for the interaction between the `View` and the `Model` and should contain primary the logic regarding `UI`.

> ```
> public GamesViewModel()
> {
>     _gameService = ServiceSingletons.GameService;
>     _gameService.GamesChanged += OnGamesChanged;
>
>     Games = new ObservableCollection<Game>(_gameService.GetAll());
> }
>
> private void OnGamesChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
> {
>     Games = new ObservableCollection<Game>(_gameService.GetAll());
> }
> ```

The `OnSomeEvent` pattern is widely used by the eventsource, the object which is raising the event. The eventhandler usually is in the form of `EventSource_Event` or `Event`. You should rename `OnGamesChanged` either to `GamesChanged` (which I prefer) or to `GameService_GamesChanged`.

I will come back to the events part later.

---

> ```
> private string _name, _exePath;
> ```

Multiple declarations on the same line makes your code less readable.

> ```
> public Game SelectedGame
> {
>     get { return _selectedGame; }
>     set
>     {
>         _selectedGame = value;
>
>         if (value == null)
>             return;
>
>         Name = value.Name;
>         ExePath = value.ExecutablePath;
>     }
> }
> ```

Omitting braces `{}`, although they are optional for single instruction `if`, can lead to error prone code.

`AddGame()` vs `RemoveGame()`

In `AddGame()` you make a call to `_gameService.Add()` which is pretty straightforward but in `RemoveGame()` you make a call to `_gameService.Delete(SelectedGame)` which seems odd to me. I would like to suggest that you rename the `Delete()` method of the `GameService` to `Remove()`.

---

**Key concerns**

> I'm using an event, GamesChanged, in the GameService class to alert my
>   ViewModel to CRUD operations. This feels wrong and slightly
>   WinForms-ish.

Well, the `GameService` shouldn't have anything to to with any UI related stuff, so it can't be neither "WinForms-ish" nor "Wpf-ish".

Having and raising events is just the way how children should talk to their parents. If the `ViewModel` should react on any `CRUD` operation of the `GameService` then using events is the way to go.

Using the `INotifyPropertyChanged` event for such a case wouldn't be good, because typically this event is used for binding clients and like you mentioned yourself

> I thought of implementing INotifyPropertyChanged in my service class, but I'm not quite sure that would work since I would have to invent a new property to watch.

which leads now to

> Because of issue 1, I needed the same instance of GameService in both GamesViewModel and ManageGamesViewModel so that they could each react to changes to the data simultaneously, e.g. adding a new game in the Manage Games screen refreshes the ComboBox on the main screen. Assuming I've taken the right approach in using an event from the service, is my use of a singleton property acceptable? In WinForms, I would have passed an instance of GameService in the constructor of the form, but I don't believe that's possible for my ViewModel because it is instantiated in XAML without arguments. Since I'm trying to stay very simple, I'd like to avoid an IoC container right now.

You don't need to use constructor injection you could simply use property injection. There would be no need to have a `Singleton` then.

> This also hinges on issue 1, but I'm skeptical of how I refresh the ObservableCollection property in the GamesViewModel and ManageGamesViewModel. I do like how simple it is, but it seems I don't even need ObservableCollection here. That could just as well be a plain ol' List.

For this part you just need to ask yourself: Do I need to react on changes made to this collection ? If the answer is Yes you should keep the `ObservableCollection<T>` otherwise skip it.

---

**Events**

I would like to suggest that you don't use the event `GamesChanged` in the way you do it now. It is adding a big overhead if you need each time to call `_gameService.GetAll()` although maybe only one `Game` is added or removed.

I would like to suggest that you add your own event arguments which contains for instance the action which took place (by using an enum) and the `Game` object in question, which would make it easier to update your objects.

Comment: Thanks! Those are good suggestions. I'm confused on how I could use property injection to avoid the singleton. Wouldn't I still need to assign the singleton instance to the property so that both ViewModels can react to the same event?

Comment: Create the `GameService` object at start of your application and pass it to each object which needs it. Should be easy to do unless I am not aware of some bear traps.

Comment: It was easy to do in WinForms. A little more complicated in WPF. I was instantiating my ViewModels in XAML which meant no constructor arguments. I'm now using the code-behind to instantiate the ViewModels which means I can pass in arguments, so it seems that is the way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You are right. You don't need the `GamesChanged` event. 
`GameService` seems to be something like a ViewModel, but the `ManageGamesViewModel` holds the games. 
I would move the `ObservableCollection<Game> Games` to the `GameService` class, because it seems that your `GameService` class has a `List` or something similar to this. Your code will look e.g. like this:

```
public GameService
{
    public ObservableCollection<Game> Games {get;set;}

    public Add(Game game)
    {
        Games.Add(game);
    }
}
```

In the `ManageGamesViewModel` you wrap `_gameService` in a public property with the `RaisePropertyChanged` Method in the setter:

```
public class ManageGamesViewModel : ViewModelBase, IDataErrorInfo 
{
    public GameService GameService
    {
        get
        {
            return this._gameService;
        }
        set
        {
            this._gameService = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("GameService");
        }
    }
}
```

And now you bind to the Games Collection like this:

```
<ListView Name="GamesListView" ItemsSource="{Binding GameService.Games}"... />
```

instead of

```
<ListView Name="GamesListView" ItemsSource="{Binding Games}" ... />
```

Comment: GameService is a service class in my domain layer. I'm hesitant to return an ObservableCollection from it because it feels like I'm forcing my domain layer to accomodate the presentation technology being used.

Comment: @SeeSharpCode, `ObservableCollection` is not a presentation technology. It is merely a collection which fires notifications when its contents are changed. It just *so happens* that WPF utilizes `INotifyCollectionChanged` in binding engine. So using `ObservableCollection` might be a valid alternative to implementing separate `GamesChanged ` event. 
You should definitely not leak your domin logic to viewmodels though and vice versa. Those should remain separate, thats kind of the whole point of MVVM. Therefore I would recommened against tuning your service into view model.